# Uniformly distributed in the disc

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

$(X_1,X_2)$ is a point uniformly distributed on the disc with radius R centred on the origin. Find the distribution and expected value of $L=\sqrt{(X_1)^2+(X_2)^2}.$
Solution: I find that $P(L \leq a)= \frac {\pi  a^2 }{\pi R^2 } = \frac {a^2}{R^2}$.

Comment: What's your question? Are you having difficulty with the problem? What exactly is the difficulty that you need us to help with?

Comment: **Hint.** What does $L$ actually represent, physically?

Comment: L is d(O,(X1,X2)) but i don't have a solution for this problem. Please, help me with a solution.

Comment: Please make *some* attempt on your own and indicate exactly *where* you are having trouble.  To get you started: because the points in the disc follow a uniform probability distribution, the probability density function $f_L(r)$ will be proportional to the size of the set of points that are distance $r$ from the centre of the circle and within the disc.  What is this set?

Answer (score 0):

**Comment:** So many claims of duplicates! Here is a simulation with $R = 1$ and a histogram
of the simulated distribution. At least maybe something useful and new, without
giving a 'screen-shot' ready answer to an obviously popular hwk problem.
For an analytic solution, think polar coordinates.

```
x = runif(10^6, -1, 1);  y = runif(10^6, -1, 1)  # random pts in square
cond = x^2 + y^2 < 1
x = x[cond]; y = y[cond]                         # keep only pts in circle
d = sqrt(x^2 + y^2)
mean(d);  sd(d)
## 0.6669966  # aprx E(D)
## 0.2356675  # aprx SD(D)
hist(d, prob=T, col="wheat")
```

[image]

Note: If the points were uncorrelated standard bivariate normally distributed,
then the answer would be a Rayleigh distribution.